# Python: installing packages and downloads

Tags: python

I am trying to set and install some packages with python. I have already installed python3 along with Anaconda.

My first question is that when I type:

```
$ python3
```

Anaconda says: `"$" is not an internal or external command`. Should I be using a different command or how can I fix this?

My second question is this: I am trying to install the packages from these four sites based on a book I got:

- NumPy: http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.10.1/user/install.html
- SciPy: http://www.scipy.org/install.html
- scikit-learn: http://scikit-learn.org/stable/install.html
- matplotlib: http://matplotlib.org/1.4.2/users/installing.html

This note was in there as well: *"If you are on Windows, you should have installed a SciPy-stack compatible version of Python 3".*

When I go to copy the line for installing the packages on windows and pasting it into my terminal, it gives the error: `"The system can not find the file specified"`

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 1):

1. Don't type the `$`, just `python3`.
2. The packages you mention are already included in Anaconda python distribution.

Answer (score 1):

1. `$` is usually used to indicate the start of a line that should be executed in a terminal window. So, therefore, remove the `$` and write everything that comes afterwards.
2. If you installed Anaconda, then you should have the `conda` command available to you. Besides `scikit-learn`, the packages should already be installed with your Anaconda distribution. What you could do is `$ conda install scikit-learn` and this should install `scikit-learn` for you.

I recommend you to look at the documentation of Anaconda at the Anaconda website (https://docs.anaconda.com/anaconda/) to learn more on how Anaconda, packages and Python works.

Comment: I tried just typing "python3" but it still does not work in the terminal

Comment: If you are currently inside the Anaconda environment, you will have to use `$ python` instead of `$ python3`, because that's what the name of the executable (most likely) is.

Answer (score 0):

Just as emmv said, a few other things in my mind:
You installed Python with Anaconda. I assume you did not add Python to PATH. You should check Anaconda website for any further installments, downloads etc. 
Anaconda uses a simple "conda" command, after all. Really, just look at Anaconda's website if you are confused.